# Show that $g_{n}(x)$ is a measurable function for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X} g_{n}=3$

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking for some ideas or suggestions on how to do the following problem:

> Let $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f: (X, \mathfrak{M}) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a measurable function with $\int_{X} f d\mu=3$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ consider the function $g_{n}: (X, \mathfrak{M}) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ given by 
>   $$g_{n}(x) := n\cdot \ln\big(1+\frac{f(x)}{n}\big)$$
>   for all $x\in X$. 
>   Show that $g_{n}(x)$ is a measurable function for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X} g_{n}=3$$

This looks like something where one would use dominated convergence or something like that. A vague idea I had was to notice that this is true when $f=3 \chi_{[0,1]}$ and in the general, when $f$ is integrable, we can approximate $f$ simple functions. I am still thinking about this, but would happy to hear suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were correct to consider the dominated convergence theorem. Indeed, since $f$ is integrable, it is finite almost everywhere, and wherever $f$ is finite, we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} g_n(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} n \ln\bigg( 1 + \frac{f(x)}{n} \bigg)= f(x).$$ Further, for all $x \in \mathbb R$, we have $1 + x \le e^x$ and thus, in particular, whenever $x \ge 0$, we have $\ln(1+x) \le x$. Hence $$g_n(x) = n\ln\bigg( 1 + \frac{f(x)}n\bigg) \le n \bigg( \frac{f(x)}{n}\bigg) = f(x)$$ so $f(x)$ serves as an integrable dominating function.

Comment: And why is $g_n$ measurable?

Comment: OP doesn't seem too concerned with that part, but the easy answer is that the composition of a continuous function and a measurable map remains measurable, and multiplying a measurable map by a constant results in another measurable map.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that
$$
h_n(x)=n\ln \Big(1+\frac{x}{n}\Big),\quad x\ge 0,
$$
is increasing, as a function of $n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} h_n(x)=x$.

In order to obtain the result sought for in the OP, one may use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem or Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: And why is $g_n$ measurable?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$m_f(t)=\{x:f(x)>t\}\\m_g(t)=\{x:g(x)>t\}$$it's not hard to show that $m_f(t)$ and $m_g(t)$ are homeomorphic therefore both are measurable or not, also $$\int_{X}fd\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}|m_f(t)|dt$$where $|.|$ denotes measure (not cardinality). Now note that the followings are equivalent$$g(x)>t\\n\ln(1+\dfrac{f(x)}{n})>t\\\dfrac{f(x)}{n}>e^{\frac{t}{n}}-1\\f(x)>n(e^{\frac{t}{n}}-1)\\m_g(t)=m_f(n(e^{\frac{t}{n}}-1))$$which yields$$\int_{X}gd\mu{=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}g_nd\mu\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}|m_{g_n}(t)|dt\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}|m_{f}(n(e^{\frac{t}{n}}-1))|dt\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}|m_{f}(t+\frac{t^2}{2n}+\frac{t^3}{6n^2}+\cdots)|dt\\=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}|m_{f}(t+\frac{t^2}{2n}+\frac{t^3}{6n^2}+\cdots)|dt\\=\int_{0}^{\infty}|m_{f}(t)|dt\\=3}$$